# Execute command through SSH

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, quoting

I am writing a script to check whether all the servers in my organization are functioning properly. One of those is Zimbra mail server. I am trying to send a mail through sendmail provided by zimbra package using the following command

```
ssh Jarvice@someip echo "Hello" | /opt/zimbra/postfix-2.7.4.2z/sbin/sendmail someuser@gmail.com
```

But I am unable to do so. I think I am making some mistake in the

```
echo "Hello" | /opt/zimbra/postfix-2.7.4.2z/sbin/sendmail someuser@gmail.com
```

part. But I don't know what it is. Can someone tell me the correct way to do so? Since I am doing this through a script, I have made sure that I can `ssh` without providing the password. I wish to fully automate the process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your local shell is dividing your command into `ssh ...` and `/opt/zimbra ...`, and then piping the two.

You have to quote the argument to ssh, so your local shell won't try to interpret it and it will be sent to the remote computer in its entirety:

```
ssh Jarvice@someip "echo \"Hello\" | /opt/zimbra/postfix-2.7.4.2z/sbin/sendmail someuser@gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two method to send mails command line from zimbra server based on ZCS Roles.

1. Send mail from Zimbra MTA
2. Send mail from mailstore,LDAP,Proxy via Zimbra MTA

```shell
/bin/awk ' BEGIN{\
               print "Subject:zimbra backup status (MTA to NAS) !\nFrom:ms2 <admin@knowledgelinux.com>"\
           }{\
               printf("%s\015\n", $0)\
           }' $LOG | sendmail -t "admin@sahara.in""
```

For more information see below link
http://www.knowledgelinux.com/how-to-send-mail-from-zimbra-command-line/

Comment: There isn't any text below the link (as in see below the table). Did you mean "see the following link"?