# How to execute in-line commands through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, bashrc

I'm struggling to execute commands through ssh, especially aliased command.

The alias I need is `ldocker` which is set in the remote `.bashrc`.

So far I tried:

```
$ssh bugs2 '. .bashrc && echo "--" && alias && echo "--"'
```

---

```
$ssh bugs2 'source .bashrc && echo "--" && alias && echo "--"'
```

---

```
$ssh bugs2 'bash "source .bashrc && alias"'
bash: source .bashrc && alias: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

---

```
$ssh bugs2 "bash \"source .bashrc && alias\""
bash: source .bashrc && alias: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

I've looked at the following posts

- [Execute command through SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28666/execute-command-through-ssh)
- [shell scripting remote commands through ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204284/shell-scripting-remote-commands-through-ssh),
- [How to properly run "top" command through SSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43496/how-to-properly-run-top-command-through-ssh)
- [How to append a file through ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266241/how-to-append-a-file-through-ssh)

but could not find any solution to my issue.

#### So my question is:

How to execute, in a single line, `.bashrc`-remotely-`aliased` commands through ssh?

Answer (score 0):

what about this :

```
ssh bugs2 "bash -ic remotealias"
```

for me it almost works, the alias is :

```
alias remotealias='echo 123123123'
```

and the output is :

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Invalid argument
bash: no job control in this shell
123123123
```

---

**EDIT:** But stealing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198378/ssh-command-execution-doesnt-consider-bashrc-bash-login-ssh-rc), the cleanest solution is to add the following line into the remote `.bashrc` file:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Comment: Using `ssh -t` instead of `ssh` will remove the job control error

Comment: It almost worked for me too, `ssh -t bugs2 'bash -ic ldocker info | head'` outputs an error with docker, it just don't take the argument..